# What's the sum of elements of this set?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Let S be a set of integers such that:

$$S = \left \{\min(\mathbf{C}, a + b - 1) | a \in \left [ \mathbf{A} \right ], b \in \left [ \mathbf{B} \right ] \right \}$$

- Note that $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are positive integers and we know $\mathbf{A} \leq \mathbf{B} \leq \mathbf{C}$
- Also $\left [ x \right ]$ stands for $\left \{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots , x \right \}$

Can you figure out sum of all S elements using $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ as parameters?

Comment: I really thank Henk for the answer to the SET version one. The real version that I forgot to mention is for MULTISET. Any IDeas?

Comment: Consider asking a separate question if you think the current answer adds value, otherwise it probably should be unaccepted which is a bit unfair to the answerer.

Comment: I see. I just made a new one. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that $1\in[\mathbf{A}],[\mathbf{B}]$, thus $\text{min}(\mathbf{C},1+1-1)=1\in S$. Now we only need to now $\text{max}(S)$, because every value in between is also in $S$, i.e. $S=[\text{max}(S)]$.

Obviously, $\text{max}(S)\leq \mathbf{C}$. However, if $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}-1<\mathbf{C}\implies\text{max}(S)=\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}-1$.

Putting all of this together, seperating the two cases, we get
$$
S =
\begin{cases}
[\mathbf{C}],  & \text{if }\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}-1\geq\mathbf{C}, \\
[\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}-1], & \text{if }\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}-1<\mathbf{C}.
\end{cases}
$$

The sum over these elements is then given by
$$
\sum S = \frac{1}{2}\;\text{max}(S)\cdot(\text{max}(S)+1).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But actually I realized that I forgot to add that S is multiset. Do you have any Idea for that?

Comment: Mmmh, I don't have any experience with multisets, but it seems to me it doesn't change much. After all, $S$ is generated using $[\mathbf{A}], [\mathbf{B}]$, which remain the same.

Comment: @Henk the difference is in the final sum, as each element occurs multiple times.  The sum will have exactly $AB$ terms, making it significantly larger.